# Why can't the JNDI name be configured in the ejb-jar.xml file?

Tags: ejb-3.0, jndi, remote-access, java-ee-5

While working with an EJB application, why do we require an extra deployment descriptor such as jBoss.xml to configure the JNDI name? Can't we do the same in the ejb-jar.xml file itself?

Comment: In Java EE you have portable JNDI names under which components must be registered. What EE spec are you referring to? JNDI names of EJB components? What views? What are you using right now in 'jBoss.xml' (?) Tell us more of what you want to achieve and what spec are you using.

Comment: i am using ejb 3.0 and i want to configure the session bean which i have coded so that the  remote client can lookup to the jndi registry and get the refrence of buisness interface.In jBoss.xml,i am just mapping the ejb name with the jndi name.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems from your comment you're interested in setting the remote EJB view JNDI name.

The point is - the JNDI name within the server is defined using Java EE 6 portable JNDI names (every container is required to bind EJBs under those names.)

However, the remote (exported) JNDI name is not specified by any document. This is one of the things that confused me some time ago.

It occurs that either you will use ACC (Application Client Container) or obey to container-specific configuration. This means that there is no portable name of telling the container to expose remote EJB view under specified JNDI names.

Further reading:

- http://java.net/projects/ejb-spec/lists/users/archive/2012-11/message/13
- http://java.net/projects/ejb-spec/lists/users/archive/2013-01/message/41